# How Do I Export A Halftone From Illustrator For Web?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, bitmap, halftone

I created a small email invitational and for the picture treatment I used bitmap halftones I created in Photoshop, saved out as PNGs, and brought into Illustrator to create the invite.

For some reason when I export the files from Illustrator to any sort of web safe file, half of the halftoned image becomes a dense black block, like this:

[image]

I can't seem to figure out how to prevent this. I tried adjusting the scale and resolution for both the invite and the PSD and nothing seems to work. Would recreating the invitational in InDesign make this work? Or is it just not possible to export a halftone bitmap this complicated for web?

Thank you for any and all answers!

Comment: What *should* it look like?

Comment: @Cai I think she said the black block shouldn't be there.

Comment: @LateralTerminal sure, but what should be there instead? It didn't appear from nowhere so there should be *something* there

Answer (score 1):

Your problem could be the following:

Bitmap halftones are normally used for print. They are usually made at a very high resolution (+1200ppi), so each raster dot can seem round when printed.

When you downscale your image to the monitor's 72ppi the halftone pattern gets so dense that it appears as a black square. The resolution is not high enough to render the individual dots.

The solution is to use a lower frequency when creating the halftone images.

If you want the exact same halftone on all the placed images, you have to make sure that they are placed at the same resolution, and that you have used the same frequency when converting to bitmap halftone.

An easy way to ensure this would be to create the full collage in Photoshop and add the halftone screen on the finished image.